# How to find the path of apache config file

Tags: apache, centos

I want to add some configuration in my Apache Web server configuration file so, anyone would help me with a command in Linux/Ubunbtu.

Comment: The file is called ‘httpd.conf’. To find it try ‘find / -name httpd.conf’

Comment: I would advise anyone to ignore the above comment. The file does not necessarily have that name. Just randomly searching for a file named x is not the answer. The answer is below, from Nic3500

Answer (score 5):

First find your httpd processes:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
root     14124  1096  0 21:46 ?        00:00:00 /opt/apache/bin/httpd -k start
httpd    14125 14124  0 21:46 ?        00:00:00 /opt/apache/bin/httpd -k start
httpd    14126 14124  0 21:46 ?        00:00:00 /opt/apache/bin/httpd -k start
httpd    14127 14124  0 21:46 ?        00:00:00 /opt/apache/bin/httpd -k start
httpd    14240  6263  0 21:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto http
```

This will tell you:

1. the path to the httpd process.  Here /opt/apache
2. *Maybe* the name and path of the configuration file, as an argument to the httpd process.  The httpd process would then be started with the `-f CONFIG-FILE` argument.

In case 2., you are done!
In case 1, go to the directory the httpd process is from and run this:

```
cd /opt/apache/bin
./apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix)
Server built:   Jun 21 2019 21:32:47
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:83
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.6.5, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/opt/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/opt/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

And there you have it!  The last line: `-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"` tells you that the configuration file is httpd.conf in the conf directory.  Since it is an absolute path, look at the value of `HTTPD_ROOT` to know where the root is for this Apache.  Here it is `-D HTTPD_ROOT="/opt/apache"`.

So the full path is: `HTTPD_ROOT/SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`.  Here, `/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf`.

---

Another method:

```
cd /opt/apache/bin
./httpd -S
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: All search results I was coming across basically just say to find the config file through trial and error by looking in the "usual places". This answer actually tells you how to find it. Thanks!